# Passing a HTML value to use in a JQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have the following scripts:

```
 $(function (movie) {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 500
            }
        });
        $("td#dialog_link").click(function (e) {     

            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
```

And the following div to display the message:

```
<div id="dialog" title="R">
<p>The value in the table is </p>
</div>
```

I just can't seem to find a way to pass in the value from the thing i'm clicking.

It's set up so when I click an element in a table, it shows the dialog, but I want it to also display the value from what i'm clicking on in the dialog at the end or middle of the message.

Please help, I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `dialog` text before the modal opens.  Something like this:

```
    $("td#dialog_link").click(function (e) {     
        $('#dialog').html('<p>The value in the table is '+$(this).text()+'</p>');
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Another option if you change your html a bit.

```
    <div id="dialog" title="R">
      <p>The value in the table is <span id="tableVal"></span></p>
    </div>

     $("td#dialog_link").click(function (e) { 
        $('#tableVal').text($(this).text());    
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/QtBb8/

Comment: How would I pass that to the <div> i'm using to store my html response though?

I'd rather do that then inline the .html(...).

Comment: Oh our trying to pass in the value from the thing your clicking.. Check my update.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you so much for your help, it's perfect.